# unable to check if File exists using Java function inside Dataweave 2

Tags: java, mule, dataweave

I wish I could check if a file exists using some `Java functions` inside `Dataweave 2.0 script`:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
import java!java::nio::file::Files::exists
import java!java::nio::file::Paths::get
---
exists(get("C:\Users\mhery\stackoverflow.csv"))
```

But I get:

> exists(get("C:\Users\mhery\stackoverflow.csv")) ' has
> errors:   Unable to resolve module with identifier
> java::nio::file::Files::exists. at 3 : 3  Unable to resolve module
> with identifier java::nio::file::Paths::get. at 4 : 4" evaluating
> expression: "%dw 2.0
> output
> application/dw import java!java::nio::file::Files::exists import
> java!java::nio::file::Paths::get
> --- exists(get("C:\Users\mhery\stackoverflow.csv"))".

I also tried other [approaches](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-java/) but got no success when importing.

Comment: Is that the complete error message? please add any remaining lines. What are the versions of Mule, Java and if using it the Java module?

Comment: @aled I added the complete error message. I am using mule 4 and java 8.

Comment: Exactly which version of Mule 4? Mule 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

You can get around that issue by using the alternate form of importing a method mentioned in the [DataWeave Java Bridge](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-cookbook-java-methods#java_bridge) documentation:

```
import exists from java!java::nio::file::Files
import get from java!java::nio::file::Paths
```

Having said that it will not work after this fix because DataWeave doesn't seem to like methods with a variable number of arguments, at least when using the Java Bridge method.

As alternatives I recommend to implement one of these:

1. If you want to use DataWeave: Encapsulate your Java logic into a Java class in your application and call that from DataWeave.
2. Avoid DataWeave and put the Java code in a Groovy script. It will probably run unmodified.